# Is it safe to upgrade Spring to latest patch version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working in a project where **Spring Framework v4.3.12** and **Spring Security v4.2.3** are being used.

Is it safe to upgrade to the latest patch version?

⋅ [Spring Framework 4.3.25](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/v4.3.25.RELEASE)

⋅ [Spring Security 4.2.13](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.2.13.RELEASE)

If I didn't know better, I would say that from a semantic versioning point of view it shouldn't be a problem. Theoretically.
However, I am about to upgrade a portal solution to the next patch version but the whole application crashes.

Comment: Have you read the release notes for each of those patches?

Comment: Yes of some of them. For example there are no release notes for Spring Security 4.2.4 only a [git tag 4.2.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.2.4.RELEASE). For the version [4.2.5](https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/05/spring-security-5-0-4-and-4-2-5-released) there is an official release and as release notes a [github link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/milestone/109?closed=1)

Comment: Thx @dur. That's it. I haven't read the Spring Framework BOM and was aware of Release Numbering. So in my case Spring Security [4.2.13](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom) builds against  4.3.23.RELEASE. Feel free to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patch versions are compatible, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#release-numbering):

> **2.3 Release Numbering**
>
> It is useful to understand how Spring Security release numbers work, as it will help you identify the effort (or lack thereof) involved in migrating to future releases of the project. Each release uses a standard triplet of integers: MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH. The intent is that MAJOR versions are incompatible, large-scale upgrades of the API. MINOR versions should largely retain source and binary compatibility with older minor versions, thought there may be some design changes and incompatible updates. PATCH level should be perfectly compatible, forwards and backwards, with the possible exception of changes which are to fix bugs and defects.
>
> The extent to which you are affected by changes will depend on how tightly integrated your code is. If you are doing a lot of customization you are more likely to be affected than if you are using a simple namespace configuration.
>
> You should always test your application thoroughly before rolling out a new version.

To handle your Spring Framework dependencies you could use the Spring Framework BOM, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom):

> **Spring Framework Bom**
>
> Spring Security builds against Spring Framework 4.3.9.RELEASE, but should work with 4.0.x. The problem that many users will have is that Spring Security’s transitive dependencies resolve Spring Framework 4.3.9.RELEASE which can cause strange classpath problems.
>
> One (tedious) way to circumvent this issue would be to include all the Spring Framework modules in a  section of your pom. An alternative approach is to include the `spring-framework-bom` within your `<dependencyManagement>` section of your `pom.xml` as shown below:
>
> **pom.xml.**
>
> ```xml
> <dependencyManagement>
>   <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
>       <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
>       <type>pom</type>
>       <scope>import</scope>
>     </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
> </dependencyManagement>
> ```
>
> This will ensure that all the transitive dependencies of Spring Security use the Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE modules.